# Athena Compilation Error: HIVE_PATH_ALREADY_EXISTS with Partitioned S3 Objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I'm experiencing an issue with AWS Athena when trying to compile a table from millions of small, partitioned S3 objects. I haven't specified where the table should be saved, and I'm encountering a HIVE_PATH_ALREADY_EXISTS error. The error message suggests that the target directory for my table already exists. Here's the error log:

```
Runtime Error in model table (models/compress_tables/table.sql)
HIVE_PATH_ALREADY_EXISTS: Target directory for table 'database.table' already exists: s3://aws-athena-query-results-1234556789-us-east-1/dbt/tables/dbt/table/e365789-fd5f-4343-b1ca-c234244f1307. You may need to manually clean the data at location...
```

I'm not sure why this error is occurring, as I didn't manually specify the output location for the table, and I thought Athena managed these paths automatically. Has anyone faced this issue before, and how did you resolve it? Is there a way to force Athena to overwrite the existing directory or to specify a new output location that avoids this issue?